# Is this guaranteed to be a safe cast?

Tags: c++

Consider the following definitions:

```
struct A {
   // ...
};

struct B : public A {}; // empty

void f(B& b) { /* use b */}

void g(A& a) {
   f(static_cast<B&>(a)); // is this a safe downcast?
}

int main() {
   A a;
   g(a);
}
```

In the above example `a` is really an instance of `A`.

Since `B` has an empty definition, I would like to know if in this specific case the call to f and its execution are undefined behaviour.

Comment: It's not really a "downcast", more like an "upcast"!

Comment: @typ1232: Casting from a supertype (aka base class) to a subtype (aka derived class) is conventionally called a "downcast", even though "base" sounds like it should be at the bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that is not a legal cast, because it is being performed on an object that is not of type `B`. Your program has undefined behavior.

Per paragraph 5.2.9/2 of the C++11 Standard:

> An lvalue of type “*cv1* `B`,” where `B` is a class type, can be cast to type “reference to cv2 `D`,” where `D` is a class
>   derived (Clause 10) from `B`, if a valid standard conversion from “pointer to `D`” to “pointer to `B`” exists (4.10),
>   *cv2* is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv1*, and `B` is neither a virtual base class
>   of `D` nor a base class of a virtual base class of `D`. The result has type “*cv2* `D`.” An xvalue of type “*cv1* `B`”
>   may be cast to type “rvalue reference to *cv2* `D`” with the same constraints as for an lvalue of type “*cv1* `B`.”
>   **If the object of type “cv1 `B`” is actually a subobject of an object of type `D`, the result refers to the enclosing
>   object of type `D`. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined**

Comment: with OP's `A` and `B`taking the `B` and `D` roles, D's derived from B, there's a valid standard conversion from `D*` to `B*`, the cv's match, there are no virtual bases.

Comment: @jthill: Yes. And the object `a` of type `A` (that would correspond to be `B` in the text from the Standard) is not actually a subobject of an object of type `B` (that would correspond to `D`), so the behavior is undefined

Answer (score 2):

No. Irrespective of what you mean by *safe*, that cast is not correct, the real object is of type `A`, not `B` so you cannot downcast to `B`.